# iOS framework built on OSX 10.12 Sierra doesn't work on OSX 10.13 High Sierra

Tags: xcode, frameworks, macos-high-sierra

I am trying to get a framework to work across various environments. I don't have as much coverage as I would like, but the framework I am building using xcode 9.2 works locally (on OSX 10.13.3 High Sierra), but not when exported to older OSX versions. The framework has been passed down to me, so I do not know much about design choices here, but the structure of the module looks like:

```
VerifySDK/
- VerifySDK/
  - Base.lproj
  - Resource/
  - several *.swift files
- VerifySDK.xcodeproj
- VerifySDK.framework
```

I am able to build the framework fine, and use it to build, archive and export fine locally (on OSX High Sierra 10.13). However, when I provide the framework to another developer (on OSX Sierra 10.12), they get an error saying

> "../ViewController.swift:10:8: Missing required module 'Resources'"

This happens on the "import VerifySDK" line in the app using this framework.

I have tried the build the other way around as well: built the framework on 10.12 and imported it on 10.13, but I get the same error.

The person who passed down the codebase had it working across all tested on various platforms (not sure if High Sierra was out at the time though), but I cannot seem to do so and am not sure where to start looking.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Based on reading around, the only way around this issue is to make the framework public and let other devs build the module themselves. Not sure if that helps, but that's the only option I have left. The issue possibly stems from swift seemingly being a second class citizen in XCode world. The projects using swift to create frameworks have some sort of local references and they seem to not work when ported over to even extremely similarly configured machines (same OS, XCode, libs etc.).

Comment: That is bad. I cant make it public, it is a commercial framework in my case. :(

Comment: In your case, did you try adding a copy files build script to copy "Resources" folder at build time?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, but adding a copy files to script wouldn't solve the issue because Resources really should be a part part of the framework being generated